# How to get dynamic data in bootstrap modal? in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, eloquent

I new to laravel I'm creating a web project which view pictures for events. In page I view one photo per event but i when user click on photo I open a bootstrap modal its body contain carousel to show the all pictures for specific event. The problem is that on clicking on a photo, I want to show associated photos from the database but it seems like javascript code (retrieve photo from db) is not executed. And I also get an error. sd is supposed to be array retrieved from query:

> undefined variable: sd

This is the code for view:

```html
<section class="no-padding" id="media">
        <div class="container-fluid">

       <ul id="hexGrid">
@foreach($items as $item)  

 <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
          <a class="hexLink" href="#" id="{{$item->id}}"  role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal"  data-target="#myModal">
             
            <img src="{{$item->pic}}" alt="" />
            <h1>sdfghjk</h1>
            <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>

          </a>
        </div>
      </li>   

@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
</section>
 
 
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>-->

  <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" hidden="true" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="panel panel-filled">
                <div class="panel-body">
                       <div class="modal-header">Events</div>
                <div class="modal-body">


 
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
         <!-- Indicators -->
 
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @foreach( $sd->pic as $photo )
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
                    @endforeach
    </ol>  


    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      @foreach( $sd->pic as $photo )
       <div class="item {{ $loop->first ? ' active' : '' }}" >
                            <img src="{{ $photo }}" alt="">
                        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('target-id');
        $.get('/media' + id, function( data ) {
        alert(data);
          $(".modal-body").html(data);
        });

      });
    });
  </script>
```

thats code at controller and route

```html
public function getpic($id)
{
     $sd = DB::table('media')->where('id', '=', $id);
     dd($sd);
     return view('event', ['sd' => $sd])->render();
}
Route::get('media/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'MediaController@getpic',
    'as' => 'media'
]);
```

Comment: 1. I think [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) is good for your case. it's easy to set and fancy style and features.
2. the key in loading different data in modal inside the same laravel view is mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43338267/1290292)

Comment: well actually script is not fetching any data from data base in order to display as if its not given the right path to controller function.i dont know why it isnt directed to right path. my problem is diffrenet from that in the post you mentioned

Comment: routes are not defined in controller. `dd()` means `die(var_dump($sd))` so I think no BLADE view will be displayed. but only the variable data and a app die.

Comment: i know that rout is not stored in controller but i want to show it here . and server doesnt die so thats what make me think its not direction to right controller

Comment: but i dont know whats wrong with the code